# Alphabet Between Encryption

Tags: code-golf

You must write a program that encrypts an input into a string of characters.

For every character `i` in the input up to the second to last character, take the `i` and `i+1` characters and encode them by writing the letters of the alphabet, in order, that range in the same direction between those chosen characters.

For example: if the original string were `bo` then it would be encoded as `cdefghijklmn`, but if the string were `boa` then `bo` is encoded as `cdefghijklmn` and `oa` is encoded as `nmlkjihgfedcb` with the final encrypted string being `cdefghijklmnnmlkjihgfedcb`.

If the original string contain zero letters between two chosen characters, such as the string `ab` then you should encrypt it as `aRb` with `R` standing for what direction in the alphabet to go in determining the original characters. The encrypted string `aRb` represents `ab` but the encrypted string `aLb` represents `ba` (`R` = right, `L` = left).

If two chosen characters in the original string are the same, such as the string `tt`, then you should encrypt it as `tZt` with `Z` standing for zero letters in between.

**Examples:**

Input: `att` Output: `bcdefghijklmnopqrstZt`

Input: `brep` Output: `cdefghijklmnopqqponmlkjihgffghijklmno`

Input: `Optimizer` Output: `oRpqrssrqponmlkjjkllkjjklmnopqrstuvwxyyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgffghijklmnopq`

**Rules:**

- You can write a program or a function.
- Your input may contain uppercase letters, so you need to put them all to lowercase before encrypting.
- You can ignore non-alphabet characters.
- One character length strings are undefined.
- Shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: I'm not sure I quite get all the rules - what's the expected output for `aabbcfcBBAa`?

Comment: Is "ab" encrypted as "aZb"? Is "aa" encrypted as "aZa"?

Comment: @Sp3000 `aZa aRb bZb bRc de ed cRb bZb bLa aZa` without any spaces.

Comment: @MtnViewMark ab = `aRb`, aa = `aZa`

Comment: What should the output be for the input `a`?

Comment: @Doorknob That is undefined, meaning it doesn't matter.

Comment: Does "You can ignore non-alphabet characters." mean that we can expect the input to be letters only or can the input have non-letters and we have to filter them out?

Comment: shouldn't `cB` in @Sp3000's test be encoded `cLb` not `cRb`?

Comment: @MtnViewMark Yes, I messed up.

Comment: @phase In your question, you wrote that the encrypted string `aLb` represents `ba`. This mean that the letters are always ordered alphabetically and `cLb` or `bLa` is invaild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, 38 bytes

```
M|strFGjHGsm?>Fd_g_d\Lgd?qFd\Z\R.:rzZ2
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M%7CstrFGjHGsm%3F%3EFd_g_d%5CLgd%3FqFd%5CZ%5CR.%3ArzZ2&input=Optimizer&debug=0)

```
M|strFGjHGsm?>Fd_g_d\Lgd?qFd\Z\R.:rzZ2
                                          Implicit: z = input(), Z = 0
                                          g is a function of a 2 letter string
                                          and an insert letter.
M                                         def g(G, H): return
    rFG                                   Take the string range between the
                                          letters in G.
   t                                      Remove the first letter to get just
                                          the letters in between.
  s                                       Concatenate.
 |                                        Logical or (if nothing in between)
       jHG                                H.join(G)
                                  rzZ     Convert input to lowercase.
                                .:   2    Take 2 letter substrings.
           m                              Map d over the substrings
            ?>Fd                          If the first character of `d`
                                          is greater than the second,
                 _g_\L                    g(d[::-1], 'L')[::-1]
                      gd                  else, g(d,
                        ?qFd              if the letters of d are the same,
                            \Z            'Z'
                              \R          else 'R')
          s                               Concatenate and print.
```

Answer (score 3):

## C - 161 Bytes - GCC

```
#define y(x) putchar(x)
main(_,z){for(_=getchar();-~(z=getchar());_=z)for(_==z?y(_),y(90),y(z):-~_==z?y(_++),y(82),y(z):_==-~z?y(_),y(76),y(z):_;_<z;y(_),_++);}
```

Will update when I get it shorter

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 253 bytes

```
(d,y=`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`)=>[...`${d}`.toLowerCase()].map((l,i,a,m=a[i-1],c=s=>y.search(s),d=(s,e)=>y.slice(c(s),c(e)).slice(1),j=c(m),k=c(l))=>m?l==m?l+'Z'+l:j+1==k?m+'R'+l:k+1==j?l+'L'+m:j>k?[...d(l,m)].reverse().join``:k>j?d(m,l):0:'').join``
```

Just by glancing you can see all the places where this can be golfed. I can probably chop off 100 bytes.

Ungolfed:

```
(d,y=`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`)=>
[...`${d}`.toLowerCase()].map((l,i,a, m=a[i-1],
 c=s=>y.search(s),
 d=(s,e)=>y.slice(c(s),c(e)).slice(1))
   =>m?
     l==m?         l+'Z'+l:
     c(m)+1==c(l)? m+'R'+l:
     c(l)+1==c(m)? l+'L'+m:
     c(m)>c(l)?    [...d(l,m)].reverse().join``:
     c(l)>c(m)?    d(m,l):  0:
'').join``
```

You can clearly see where this can be golfed in the `?:` sequence.

---

ES5 Snippet:

```js
function t(d) {
    var y = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    return (d+'').toLowerCase().split('').map(function (l,i,a) {
        var m = a[i - 1],
            c = function (s) {
                return y.search(s)
            },
            d = function (s,e) {
                return y.slice( c(s), c(e) ).slice(1);
            };
       return m ? 
              l == m           ? l + 'Z' + l :
              c(m) + 1 == c(l) ? m + 'R' + l :
              c(l) + 1 == c(m) ? l + 'L' + m :
              c(m) > c(l)      ? d(l,m).split('').reverse().join('') :
              c(l) > c(m)      ? d(m,l)                              :
              0 : ''
    }).join('');
}

// Demo
document.getElementById('go').onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = t(document.getElementById('input').value)
};
```

```html
<div style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"><h2 style="font-family:sans-serif">Encoding Snippet</h2><div><div  style="background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><input placeholder="Text here..." id="input"><button id='go'>Encode!</button></div><br><div style="background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><span style="font-family:sans-serif;">Output:</span><br><pre id="output" style="background-color:#DEDEDE;padding:1em;border-radius:2px;overflow-x:auto;"></pre></div></div></div>
```

Comment: By setting `y`, can you use a different alphabet/set of characters?

Comment: @phase yeah, that contains all the characters the program uses.

Answer (score 1):

## Python <del>343</del> 334 bytes

```
import sys,re,string
j=''.join
a=string.ascii_lowercase
for l in sys.stdin:
 s,L=re.sub('[^a-z]','',l.lower()).strip(),[]
 for i,c in enumerate(s[:-1]):o=s[i+1:i+2]or c;b,d=a.index(c),a.index(o);L.extend(j(e[1])for e in[(c==o,[c,'Z',c]),(c<o,(a[b+1:d],[c,'R',o])[b+1==d]),(c>o,(a[d+1:b][::-1],[c,'L',o])[b-1==d])]if e[0])
 print(j(L))
```

Code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/1bkTYs).

First golf ever. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Welcome to the site! A couple of suggestions: Using semicolons to separate your lines instead of newlines is typically shorter, as it avoids indentation. Also, you can alias `''.join` to something shorter, like `j`, which saves bytes because you use it twice. Take a look at [this page](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) if you want more tips.

Comment: Hi, thanks! How would I go about aliasing a built-in's method invocation to save space? For example this is illegal in all pythons `str.j=str.join` since 'str' is a built-in type. I could do something like `j=lambda L:''.join(L)` (21 bytes), but the definition alone is as twice as long as `''.join(L)` (10 bytes).

Comment: It's very simple: `j=''.join`

Comment: Super! I overthought that one! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

## K5, 77 bytes

*ouch*

```
,/{$[(p:d>0)&3>d:1+x-y;"LZR"@d;`c$$[p;1_y+!x-y;|1_x+!y-x]]}':{(x;x+32)@x<97}'
```

Explanation coming after more golfing.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 168 bytes

```
import Data.Char
s=succ
b#a|a==b=[a,'Z',b]|s a==b=[a,'R',b]|a==s b=[a,'L',b]|a>b=reverse$a#b|a<b=[s a..pred b]
e=concat.(tail>>=zipWith(#)).map toLower.filter isLetter
```

running:

```
λ: e "att"
"bcdefghijklmnopqrstZt"
λ: e "brep"
"cdefghijklmnopqqponmlkjihgffghijklmno"
λ: e "Optimizer"
"oRpqrssrqponmlkjjkllkjjklmnopqrstuvwxyyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgffghijklmnopq"
λ: e "aabbcfcBBAa"
"aZaaRbbZbbRcdeedcLbbZbbLaaZa"
```

Comment: Nice. 1 byte to save: use both `id=<<` instead of `concat` and a list comprehension instead of `map` and `filter`: `e x=id=<<(tail>>=zipWith(#))[toLower i|i<-x,isLetter i]`

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 185 bytes

```
import Data.Char
s=succ
p=pred
f(a:b:c)|b==s a=q 'R'|a==s b=q 'L'|a==b=q 'Z'|a<b=[s a..p b]++n|a>b=[p a,p$p a..s b]++n where q m=a:m:b:n;n=f(b:c)
f _=[]
g x=f[toLower e|e<-x,isLetter e]
```

Usage: `g "brep"` -> `"cdefghijklmnopqqponmlkjihgffghijklmno"`.

How it works: `g` throws away all non-letters and converts the letters to lower case and calls `f` to do the encryption. Depending on the first two characters `f` inserts `R`, `L` or `Z` or builds the sequence in-between and and appends the result of a recursive call of itself with the tail of the input.